# Simplifying $\frac1{1+x}+\frac2{1+x^2}+\frac4{1+x^4}+\frac8{1+x^8}+\frac{16}{x^{16}-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We need to simplify $$\dfrac{1}{1+x}+\dfrac{2}{1+x^2}+\dfrac{4}{1+x^4}+\dfrac{8}{1+x^8}+\dfrac{16}{x^{16}-1}$$

The last denominator can be factored and we can get all the other denominators as factors of $x^{16}-1$. I tried handling the expressions in pairs,starting from the right.I also tried to take a common factor of two out of the numerators to help simplify,but that has yielded nothing.I then tried multiplying all the fractions to get $x^{16}-1$ in the denominator but that worsens things(I think so anyway).

So after doing the above things(and much more),I feel like I am running out of ideas.A really small **hint** will be appreciated.

Comment: If you split that last factor into two fractions with denominators $(x^8\pm 1)$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\frac{16}{x^{16}-1}=\frac{8}{x^8-1}+\frac{-8}{x^8+1}$$

So the $4^{th}$ term of the original sum and the $2^{nd}$ part of the decomposition above are canceled. You are left with:
$$
\dfrac{1}{1+x}+\dfrac{2}{1+x^2}+\dfrac{4}{1+x^4}+\dfrac{8}{x^{8}-1}
$$
Continue similarly. In the end you will get $\frac{1}{x-1}$.

Comment: Ah,I should have thought of PFD in resolving this problem.Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @rah4927 This is what I suggested originally in my comment.

Comment: I thought you were asking me to factor the denominator(sorry I didn't read your comment properly).

Comment: @Test123. I think that you will get $\frac{1}{x-1}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, it was a typos there. Thank you

Comment: If you knew the number of typo's I can make !

Comment: Another way is to add $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ to our expression and see how the sum telescopes.

Answer (score 4):

More generally,
$$ \sum_{n=0}^N \dfrac{2^n}{1+x^{2^n}} = \dfrac{2^{N+1}}{1-x^{2^{N+1}}} - \dfrac{1}{1-x}$$
as can be proven by induction.

Comment: Similarly, $$\sum_{n=0}^N \dfrac{3^n (2 + x^{3^n})}{1 + x^{3^n} + x^{2 \cdot 3^n}} = \dfrac{3^{N+1}}{1 - x^{3^{N+1}}} - \dfrac{1}{1 - x}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Add $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ to the given expression and see the sum telescope.